# Is binomial coefficient integer? by induction.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

To prove $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ is an integer, use Mathematical Induction on $k$

Base Step: $\binom{n}{0}=\binom{n}{n}=1$

Inductive Step: Assume that $\binom{n}{k}$, $k=1,2,...,n-1$ are all integers. We need to show that $\binom{n+1}{k}$, $k=1,2,...,n$ are all integer

Given $k=1,2,...,n$

$\binom{n+1}{k}=\frac{(n+1)!}{k!(n-k+1)!}$

$=\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}\frac{n+1}{(n-k+1)k}$

$=\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}(\frac{1}{(n-k+1)}+\frac{1}{k})$

$=\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k+1)!}+\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$

$=\binom{n}{k-1}+\binom{n}{k}$

Is this a complete and correct proof ? If not, what is wrong with it ?

Comment: What you are doing is inducting on $n$, not $k$. Otherwise, this is valid. You do have a small typo where you say $\frac{1}{(n-k+1)k}$ instead of $\frac{1}{n-k+1}$.

Comment: but do not I have to induct on k, also ? Does this still say binomial coefficient is an integer ?

Comment: You are doing an induction over n here, for this proof to be correct, the base step should be considered for n=1 and for all k from 0 to n=1 (i.e. k=0 & k=1).

Comment: And you should also not forget to check the trivial case k=n+1 in your inductive step.